# Python Error: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python

When running this code below the code appears:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import loadmat

mat = loadmat("/home/sami/sami/Dataset/mat/2018-03-11-19-42-58_atis_humanity_star_slewing_td.mat")
matTD = mat['TD']
matX = matTD['x'][0,0]
matY = matTD['y'][0,0]
matTs = matTD['ts'][0,0].astype('int32')
matP = matTD['p'][0,0]
```

It's happenning on these line:

> matX = matTD['x'][0,0]
>
> matY = matTD['y'][0,0]
>
> matTs = matTD['ts'][0,0].astype('int32')
>
> matP = matTD['p'][0,0]

This is the output error:

```
    matX = matTD['x'][0,0]
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

This is how my matrix looks like:

```
[[      122       209         0 665074460]
 [       13        68         0 665074490]
 [      152        30         0 665074603]
 ...
 [      270        56         0 694569547]
 [      270        56         0 694569547]
 [      152        30         0 694569619]]
```

Comment: You probably want `:`, not `,`…?

Comment: I tried the same error shows up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this code. The solution is below:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
import numpy as np
mat = loadmat("/home/sami/sami/Dataset/data/test2/test2.mat")

matTD = mat['TD']
matX = mat['TD'][:,0]
matY = mat['TD'][:,1]
matP = mat['TD'][:,2]
matT = mat['TD'][:,3].astype('int32')
nEvents = matT.shape[0]
events = np.zeros((nEvents,4))

events[:,0] = matX.flatten()
events[:,1] = matY.flatten()
events[:,3] = matT.flatten()
events[:,2] = matP.flatten()


np.save("/home/sami/sami/Dataset/data/test1/test1.npy",events.astype('int32'))
```

The code meant to convert a .mat file to .npy, and I just didn't slice through the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It basically says that you cannot use string, e.g. `'x'` for indexing inside square brackets.

`mat` is dict as per scipy docs (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html). So it has structure like `{'name': [data]}`. You got `[data]` with your first `matTD = mat['TD']` and it appears that `matTD` (`[data]`) type is not a `dict` anymore, so you cannot use string for indexing. Go and check what is `matTD` type to understand how you can index it.

Or probably, you need to continue to use `mat['x']` instead of `matTD['x']`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, mat is dict and matTD became "numpy.ndarray", and using mat instead of matTD didn't actually work

Comment: @samiarja, there are so many things one can do with numpy ndarrays, but idexing with string is not one of them (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html). Why do you expect your code to work?